# What is the most efficient way to search a block device for valid (filesystem) superblocks?

Tags: filesystems, search, block-device, superblock

I have a block device that contains some valid filesystem (including the main and backup superblocks) at some unknown offset with some unknown block size. In my case I happen to know that it's an ext4 filesystem with 4KiB blocks, but I'm hoping for a solution that will work for any OS-supported filesystem. What is the most efficient way to find its offset?

My current plan is to run fsck on every single byte-offset until it returns successfully. Obviously this is resource-intensive and slow, but I have yet to find or come up with a better tool or method to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to use [gpart](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/gpart.8.html) for this. It is supposed to find partitions and maybe you never had one but the approach is the same. You can have it restore a partition which never existed. That will give you the position of the filesystem. After that you can delete the partition table.